# How to set a DynamoDB Map property value, when the map doesn't exist yet

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How do you "upsert" a property to a DynamoDB row. E.g. `SET address.state = "MA"` for some item, when `address` does not yet exist?

I feel like I'm having a chicken-and-egg problem because DynamoDB doesn't let you define a sloppy schema in advance.

If `address` DID already exist on that item, of type `M` (for Map), the internet tells me I could issue an UpdateExpression like:

`SET #address.#state = :value`

with `#address`, `#state`, and `:value` appropriately mapped to `address`, `state`, and `MA`, respectively.

But if the `address` property does **not** already exist, this gives an error:

'''
ValidationException: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
'''

So.. it appears I either need to:

1. Figure out a way to "upsert" `address.state` (e.g., `SET address = {}; SET address.state = 'MA'` in a single command)

or

2. Issue three (!!!) roundtrips in which I try it, `SET address = {};` on failure, and then try it again.

If the latter.... how do I set a blank map?!?

Ugh.. I like Dynamo, but unless I'm missing something obvious this is a bit crazy..

Comment: Which language sdk you are using?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: In the latter case, I think you can combine steps 2 and 3 by setting a map pre-filled with final data instead of a blank map.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it with two round trips, the first conditionally sets an empty map for `address` if it doesn't already exist, and the second sets the `state`:

```
db.update({
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #a = :value',
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#a)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":value": {},
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#a': 'address'
    }
}, ...);
```

Then:

```
db.update({
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #a.#b = :v',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#a': 'address',
        '#b': 'state'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':v': 'whatever'
    }
}, ...);
```

Comment: I did a variation on this, by putting an `attribute_exists` condition on the second call, and supplying the attribute in the map on the first call.  Then you have one call that sets the map (with your attribute) if there's no map yet, and a second call that adds the attribute but only if the map already exists.  Then you can issue both calls in parallel, and one will always succeed and the other will always fail, but either way you will get your map in there with the attribute you want, and you don't have to wait between calls, reducing latency.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot set nested attributes if the parent document does not exist. Since `address` does not exist you cannot set the attribute `province` inside it. You can achieve your goal if you set `address` to an empty map when you create the item. Then, you can use the following parameters to condition an update on an attribute `address.province` not existing yet.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Image',
    Key: {
        Id: 'dynamodb.png'
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET address.province = :ma',
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(address.province)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':ma': 'MA'
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
};
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

By the way, I had to replace state with province as state is a reserved word.

Comment: You can get around the reserved word problem using name placeholders.  For example your `UpdateExpression` would be `'SET #a.#b = :ma'` and your `ConditionExpression` would be `'attribute_not_exists(#a.#b)'`, then you just need to map them with `ExpressionAttributeNames = { '#a': 'address', '#b': 'state' }`.

Comment: This is the approach I'm taking for this. Where rather than have sequential update expressions outside of a transaction, I am opting to create the empty earlier along in the application. For my use case, the map holds details for a user. I'm initializing the empty map when the user is created so that it's available for any subsequent calls to that object.

Comment: @leftclickben that does not work when `a` doesn't exist as at leats an empty object on the record. In my update command, I use ExpressionAttributeNames like in your example, but if `a` isn't there, it still errors.

Answer (score 1):

Another totally different method is to simply create the `address` node when creating the parent document in the first place.  For example assuming you have a hash key of `id`, you might do:

```
db.put({
    Item: {
        id: 42,
        address: {}
    }
}, ...);
```

This will allow you to simply set the `address.state` value as the `address` map already exists:

```
db.update({
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #a.#b = :v',
    AttributeExpressionNames: {
        '#a': 'address',
        '#b': 'state'
    },
    AttributeExpressionValues: {
        ':v': 'whatever'
    }
}, ...);
```

Comment: The challenge with this is answer is that it presumes that the need for the address field was known when the schema was first defined (and data was first inserted). Part of the reason to use a schema-less data store is to allow flexibility (to evolve your schema) and one of the reasons for this sort of requirement is to simplify "migration" when the schema expands.

Answer (score 0):

Some kotlin code to do this recursively regardless how deep it goes. It sets existence of parent paths as condition and if condition check fails, recursively creates those paths first. It has to be in the library's package so it can access those package private fields/classes.

```kotlin
package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.xspec

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.xspec.ExpressionSpecBuilder.attribute_exists

fun Table.updateItemByPaths(hashKeyName: String, hashKeyValue: Any, updateActions: List<UpdateAction>) {
    val parentPaths = updateActions.map { it.pathOperand.path.parent() }
            .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
            .toSet()    // to remove duplicates
    try {
        val builder = ExpressionSpecBuilder()
        updateActions.forEach { builder.addUpdate(it) }
        if (parentPaths.isNotEmpty()) {
            var condition: Condition = ComparatorCondition("=", LiteralOperand(true), LiteralOperand(true))
            parentPaths.forEach { condition = condition.and(attribute_exists<Any>(it)) }
            builder.withCondition(condition)
        }
        this.updateItem(hashKeyName, hashKeyValue, builder.buildForUpdate())
    } catch (e: ConditionalCheckFailedException) {
        this.updateItemByPaths(hashKeyName, hashKeyValue, parentPaths.map { M(it).set(mapOf<String, Any>()) })
        this.updateItemByPaths(hashKeyName, hashKeyValue, updateActions)
    }
}

private fun String.parent() = this.substringBeforeLast('.', "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a helper function I wrote in Typescript that works for this a single level of nesting using a recursive method.

I refer to the top-level attribute as a column.

```
//usage
await setKeyInColumn('customerA', 'address', 'state', "MA")
```

```js
  // Updates a map value to hold a new key value pair. It will create a top-level address if it doesn't exist.
    
    static async setKeyInColumn(primaryKeyValue: string, colName: string, key: string, value: any, _doNotCreateColumn?:boolean) {

        const obj = {};
        obj[key] = value; // creates a nested value like {address:value}


        // Some conditions depending on whether the column already exists or not

        const ConditionExpression = _doNotCreateColumn ? undefined:`attribute_not_exists(${colName})`
        const AttributeValue = _doNotCreateColumn? value : obj;
        const UpdateExpression = _doNotCreateColumn? `SET ${colName}.${key} = :keyval `: `SET ${colName} = :keyval ` ;


        try{
            const updateParams = {
                TableName: TABLE_NAME,
                Key: {key:primaryKeyValue},
                UpdateExpression,
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":keyval": AttributeValue
                },
                ConditionExpression,
                ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
            }
            const resp = await docClient.update(updateParams).promise()

            if (resp && resp[colName]) {
                return resp[colName];
            }
            
        }catch(ex){
            //if the column already exists, then rerun and do not create it
            if(ex.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException'){
               return this.setKeyInColumn(primaryKeyValue,colName,key, value, true)
            }
            console.log("Failed to Update Column in DynamoDB")
            console.log(ex);
            return undefined
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got quite similar situation. I can think of only a one way to do this in 1 query/atomically.

**Extract map values to top level attributes.**

#### Example

Given I have this post item in DynamoDB:

```json
{
  "PK": "123",
  "SK": "post",
  "title": "Hello World!"
}
```

And I want to later add an analytics entry to same partition:

```json
{
   "PK": "123",
   "SK": "analytics#december",
   "views": {
      // <day of month>: <views>
      "1": "12",
      "2": "457463",
      // etc

   }
}
```

Like in your case, it's not possible to increment/decrement `views` days counters in single query if analytics item nor `views` map might not exist (could be later feature or don't want to put empty items).

### Proposed solution:

```json
{
   "PK": "123",
   "SK": "analytics#december",
   // <day of month>: <views>
   "1": "12", // or "day1" if "1" seems too generic
   "2": "457463",
   // etc
   }
}
```

Then you could do something like this (increment +1 example):

```json
{
  UpdateExpression: "SET #day = if_not_exists(#day, 0) + 1",
  AttributeExpressionNames: {
    '#day': "1"
  }
}
```

- if day attribute value doesn't exist, set default value to 0
- if item in database doesn't exist, update API adds a new one