# How to insert a map as attribute value when attribute does not yet exist with DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Could someone please tell me how to set a map as a value for an attribute that does not yet exist. I've been trying an update expression `"SET MyAttr.#key = :val"`, but that only works if the attribute exists and if the value of the attribute is already a map.

I tried using `"ADD MyAttr.#key = :val"` instead, but then I get:

> Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "=", near: "#key = :val"

I'm using Java. Note that I'm using an attempting an UpdateItem request to do this. It just occurred to me that maybe this doesn't work with maps. I just assumed it would because I've always been able to have a new item and/or attribute created with an update request if doesn't already exist (with other attribute value data types like string, number etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that we have the following Item in our DynamoDB Table:

```
{
  "id": "91c2b60d-c428-403c-be42-8657b4f20669",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

and we want to add custom attributes that we have in a Map:

```
Map<String, String> customAttributes = new HashMap<>();
customAttributes.put("age", "21");
customAttributes.put("gender", "Male");

AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
DynamoDB dynamodb = new DynamoDB(client);

Table table = dynamodb.getTable("users");
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
          .withPrimaryKey("id", "91c2b60d-c428-403c-be42-8657b4f20669")
          .withUpdateExpression("set #customAttributes = :customAttributes")
          .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#customAttributes", "customAttributes"))
          .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withMap(":customAttributes", customAttributes))
          .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);

UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
System.out.println(outcome.getItem().toJSONPretty());
```

The result:

```
{
  "id" : "91c2b60d-c428-403c-be42-8657b4f20669",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe",
  "customAttributes" : {
    "gender" : "Male",
    "age" : "21"
  }
```

}

Now, if we want to add a new attribute to the customAttributes map:

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("id", "91c2b60d-c428-403c-be42-8657b4f20669")
    .withUpdateExpression("set customAttributes.#occupation = :value")
    .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#occupation", "occupation"))
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":value", "Programmer"))
    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);

UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);

System.out.println(outcome.getItem().toJSONPretty());
```

I suggest that you take a look at: [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html), it will save you tons of lines of code.

Comment: This does answer the question that I asked and it works. But is it possible to perform an update whereby Dynamo will add to the map if it already exists? The solution you provided will overwrite any existing map. Or do I have to query for the item first, then create a different `UpdateItemSpec` based on whether or not the item/attr currently exists?

Comment: Yes, it's possible! I'll edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what I'm looking for is a one-shot update that will either a). Create a map with my key/value pair and set the map as value of my attribute, if the item and/or attribute do not yet exist, or b). update the existing map in my attribute with the specified key/value pair. I think this is not possible in a single request though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377729/how-to-set-a-dynamodb-map-property-value-when-the-map-doesnt-exist-yet?rq=1