# DynamoDB if attribute doesn't exist create it, in node.js

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update a user objects attribute which may not exist.

The attribute is called `claimed` which itself will have a property for each currency type `#c1` (USD, euro, ect). A user can have multiple currencies but starts with none so `claimed` may or may not exist on a user object.

My initial draft was:

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'myproject-user',
  Key: {"id":req.user.sub},
  UpdateExpression: 'set claimed.#c1 = :o',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":o": req.body.currency
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames:{ "#c1": req.body.currency.type },
  ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
```

This returns the error:

```
"Error: ValidationException: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update"
```

I've tried some variations using `if_not_exists` but I can't seem to get it working. How can I modify the params to have the desired effect?

Comment: is it acceptable to do 2 calls? one to check if the map exists and then another one for the update?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I guess if I have no other choice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377729/how-to-set-a-dynamodb-map-property-value-when-the-map-doesnt-exist-yet has some more info on this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(<YOUR_ATTRIBUTE>)"`

for example:

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'myproject-user',
  Key: {"id":req.user.sub},
  UpdateExpression: 'set claimed.#c1 = :o',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":o": req.body.currency
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames:{ "#c1": req.body.currency.type },
  ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(claimed.#c1)",
  ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
```